# What kind of pedal do I have and what shoes do I need to buy?

Tags: pedals, beginner

Based on my limited research, I think these are SPD-SL clips? But I really just want to know what shoes I can get that will clip into these. I don't ride my bike a ton, so I just want your normal, run-of-the-mill shoes for these pedals.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Your photo is a bit tight; do you have one that shows the entire pedal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are not clipless pedals and you don't need any kind of special shoes. Those are pedals with toe clips and are meant to be used with regular running shoes.

Comment: Actually, old-school cycling shoes (or even a scuffed-up pair of Oxford dress shoes) would be better.  You want something with a moderately stiff (but not too-stiff) sole.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I used running shoes and my pinky toe was killing me, something with a stiffer sole might work better. With the little teeth on that metal thing I thought it would clip into something on the bottom of my shoe but I guess not!

Comment: @ToastyMallows : if the metal thing annoys you just replace it by a washer under each screw-head.

Comment: Before clipless pedals, serious cycling shoes would have slotted cleats that would match the metal part and the raised rear edge of the pedal. Once straps were tightened, feet could not be detached from pedals without releasing the straps. These pedals certainly weren't intended for running shoes.